# CakePHP get url params outside controller

Tags: cakephp

Anybody know, how to get url array params outside controller (for example bootstrap.php)?

Comment: Manually using $_SERVER vars maybe? Why do you need it that early? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @mark: because i must setting some data before Router::connect(), I descript my mainly problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14453909/182823

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP is still PHP at the end of the day, so you can use any valid PHP method to achieve this. Like:

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    // A querystring was set...
}
```

Or

```
$url = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if (!empty($url['query'])) {
     // A querystring was set...
}
```

After that you can do anything else that you want to do.

Comment: thanks but this no a array, yeah CakePHP is still PHP, but I use Router::url(), I thinks is better for CakePHP

Comment: I would like see url param, but now I see only url (like in address bar in browser), but ok.